# Performance impact redirect filesize htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have a `.htaccess` file and it about 8,000 lines long, about 7,800 of these lines are redirects or redirect matches. 3/4 of our htaccess redirects are `Redirect 301`'s and and the rest are `RedirectMatch 301 ^`'s. How long should a `.htaccess` be before it starts to affect the performance of the website. We took all of the redirect out of the htaccess a few weeks ago and we didn't see and difference in performance. However, I think that soon the file may get too long. I usually put about a 100 redirects in a day as we have so many pages which need to be redirected.

How long should a htaccess be? and do you know any other solution for redirects?

Comment: it depends on the redirects. but perhaps using a regex might be easier. can you give an example of a couple of redirects?

Comment: We have a ecommerce platform running on magento, we use some regex but because the bulk of our redirects are to do with products we can't use regex for them.

Comment: But magento has its own redirect system for products and categories. And if you are using magento, i doubt a `htaccess` file is going to be your biggest performance problem :)

Comment: But magento's redirect system aren't actually a proper redirect as they don't happen server side. But that still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I believe they are a proper redirect server side. Magento does not run on the client.... Afaik you can make it a `301` or `302`. But i did answer it though. You are using `apache` with `magento`. The performance of your website won't be affected that much with `htaccess`, because there are other things which slow significantly more

Comment: You didn't as the main question was about how long a htaccess should actually be. Also, the magento redirects are slower than using the htaccess,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit on how big a `.htaccess` file can be, the only limit will be the limit of the file size of your OS. Or how much memory you got available on your server, because the entire file needs to be put into memory, and I believe this happens with every request made from the client (in the early days of `apache`, no idea if that is still valid.. probably not.. now that i think about it :)).

Performance wise there can be a significant impact with a very big `.htaccess` file (couple MBs). Because apache reads the `.htaccess` file from top to bottom. Definitely for pages where it cannot find a match, because it has to go through the entire list.

An alternative to this could be to use the [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html) directive and create a so called hash file in a database. This could improve performance.

Another option, which also involves a database, would be to leverage the magento redirect functionality.

I believe some benchmark tests can give you an idea what the fastest solution will be